# Get row count of all output of proc in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, rowcount

How can I get rowcount of all outputs in stored procedure?

e.g.

```
Create Proc Test 
AS Begin 
  select top 10 * from sysobjects 
  select top 20* from sysobjects 
End
```

`@@rowcount` will return the outputs row count. But in my case there are 2 outputs. `@@rowcount` will return only last output only.

```
exec Test
select @@rowcount
```

This will return only 20. But I need 10, 20

Any way to achieve?

Comment: As stated in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 `@@rowcount` Returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. To get `10` & `20` You need to do that inside your stored procedure

Comment: You can ensure `SET NOCOUNT` is `OFF` then parse the "x rows affected" messages. But much cleaner just to calculate this inside the stored proc itself as already suggested in other answers

Comment: The proc given is sample, in production there are procs with multiple outputs. I see people are suggesting to get count inside proc. The thing is I cant change anything in procs. But i need to get no.of rows affected.

Comment: @MartinSmith : Good suggestion will try to parse x rows affected message. Any leads to get those messages in a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestRowCount   
    @rowcount1 INT OUTPUT,
    @rowcount2 INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  select top 10 * from sysobjects 
  SET @rowcount1 = @@ROWCOUNT
  select top 20* from sysobjects 
  SET @rowcount2 = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Calling Procedure as follows :

```
DECLARE @rowcount1 INT,
        @rowcount2 INT;
EXEC dbo.TestRowCount @rowcount1 = @rowcount1 OUTPUT, -- int
                      @rowcount2 = @rowcount2 OUTPUT  -- int
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
Create Proc Test 
AS Begin 
  select top 10 * from sysobjects 
  select @@rowcount 
  select top 20* from sysobjects 
  select @@rowcount 
End
```

Then execute the query:

```
exec Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows affected by the last statement, so one possible approach (to get the total row count from all `SELECT` statements) is to define an `output` parameter in your stored procedure:

Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestRowCount 
    @RowCount int OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET @RowCount = 0

    select top 10 * from sysobjects
    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + @@ROWCOUNT

    select top 20 * from sysobjects 
    SET @RowCount = @RowCount + @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Result:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @RowCount int
EXECUTE @RC = TestRowCount @RowCount OUTPUT
SELECT @RowCount
```

If you want to get the count of rows from each `SELECT` statement, use something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestRowCount
AS 
BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE #Tmp (RC int)

    select top 10 * from sysobjects
    INSERT INTO #Tmp (RC) VALUES (@@ROWCOUNT)

    select top 20 * from sysobjects 
    INSERT INTO #Tmp (RC) VALUES (@@ROWCOUNT)

    SELECT * FROM #Tmp
    DROP TABLE #Tmp
END
```